# Do 'Intermediate IObservables' without final subscribers get kept in memory for the lifetime of the root IObservable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, idisposable

For example, consider this:

```
    public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return eventStream.Where(e => e is T).Cast<T>().Subscribe(observer);
    }
```

The `eventStream` is a long lived source of events. A short lived client will use this method to subscribe for some period of time, and then unsubscribe by calling `Dispose` on the returned `IDisposable`.

However, while the `eventStream` still exists and should be kept in memory, there has been 2 new `IObservables` created by this method - the one returned by the `Where()` method that is presumably held in memory by the `eventStream`, and the one returned by the `Cast<T>()` method that is presumably held in memory by the one returned by the `Where()` method.

How will these 'intermediate IObservables' (is there a better name for them?) get cleaned up? Or will they now exist for the lifetime of the `eventStream` even though they no longer have subscriptions and no one else references them except for their source `IObservable` and therefor will never have subscriptions again?

If they are cleaned up by informing their parent they no longer have subscriptions, how do they know nothing else has taken a reference to them and may at some point later subscribe to them?

Comment: I haven’t been able to verify this, but I suspect that .Subscribe returns you something that, when disposed, will chain-dispose all the temporary observables too.

Comment: I thought that initially too, but read the last sentence of my question. How do the temporary observables know no one else has taken a reference to them and may be subscribed to at some point later?

Comment: I don’t know what actually happens, sorry. But one way this _could_ work is that .Subscribe increments reference counts (which bubbles up the parent chain), and .Dispose decrements them, disposing if it hits zero.

Comment: @Random832 It doesn't really matter, the question doesn't depend on it (other than it implements `IObservable<object>`). If your just wondering out of curiosity though, it is actually a `Subject<object>` (The class is a publisher-subscriber event broker).

Comment: Well, I wasn't familiar with reactive or observables, so I was trying to figure out what extension methods were in effect so I could look up documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, while the eventStream still exists and should be kept in memory, there has been 2 new IObservables created by this method - the one returned by the Where() method that is presumably held in memory by the eventStream, and the one returned by the Cast() method that is presumably held in memory by the one returned by the Where() method.

You have this backward.  Let's walk through the chain of what is going on.

```
IObservable<T> eventStream; //you have this defined and assigned somewhere

public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(IObserver<T> observer)
{
    //let's break this method into multiple lines

    IObservable<T> whereObs = eventStream.Where(e => e is T);
    //whereObs now has a reference to eventStream (and thus will keep it alive), 
    //but eventStream knows nothing of whereObs (thus whereObs will not be kept alive by eventStream)
    IObservable<T> castObs = whereObs.Cast<T>();
    //as with whereObs, castObs has a reference to whereObs,
    //but no one has a reference to castObs
    IDisposable ret = castObs.Subscribe(observer);
    //here is where it gets tricky.
    return ret;
}
```

What `ret` does or does not have a reference to depends on the implementation of the various observables.  From what I have seen in Reflector in the Rx library and the operators I have written myself, most operators do not return disposables that have a reference to the operator observable itself.

For example, a basic implementation of `Where` would be something like (typed directly in the editor, no error handling)

```
IObservable<T> Where<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
      {
         return source.Subscribe(v => if (filter(v)) obs.OnNext(v),
                                 obs.OnError, obs.OnCompleted);
      }
}
```

Notice that the disposable returned will have a reference to the filter function via the observer that is created, but will not have a reference to the `Where` observable.  `Cast` can be easily implemented using the same pattern.  In essence, the operators become observer wrapper factories.

The implication of all this to the question at hand is that the intermediate IObservables are eligible for garbage collection *by the end of the method*.  The filter function passed to `Where` stays around as long as the subscription does, but once the subscription is disposed or completed, only `eventStream` remains (assuming it is still alive).

**EDIT** for supercat's comment, let's look at how the compiler might rewrite this or how you would implement this without closures.

```
class WhereObserver<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    WhereObserver<T>(IObserver<T> base, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        _base = base;
        _filter = filter;
    }

    IObserver<T> _base;
    Func<T, bool> _filter;

    void OnNext(T value)
    {
        if (filter(value)) _base.OnNext(value);
    }

    void OnError(Exception ex) { _base.OnError(ex); }
    void OnCompleted() { _base.OnCompleted(); }
}

class WhereObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    WhereObservable<T>(IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        _source = source;
        _filter = filter;
    }

    IObservable<T> source;
    Func<T, bool> filter;

    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return source.Subscribe(new WhereObserver<T>(observer, filter));
    }
}

static IObservable<T> Where(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return new WhereObservable(source, filter);
}
```

You can see that the observer does not need any reference to the observable that generated it and the observable has no need to track the observers it creates.  We didn't even make any new IDisposable to return from our subscribe.

In reality, Rx has some actual classes for anonymous observable/observer that take delegates and forward the interface calls to those delegates.  It uses closures to create those delegates.  The compiler does not need to emit classes that actually implement the interfaces, but the spirit of the translation remains the same.

Comment: Thanks Gid, stepping through it like that and the sample `Where` implementation helped it click for me. (I really should of got off my ass and opened Reflector up). I've posted my own answer as it wouldn't fit as a comment and I wanted to summarize your answer combined with the results of my reasoning. Can you have a read through it and confirm? I'll leave this question open for now as I'm not sure if I should accept your answer or mine? Yours helped, but mine now gets straight to the point of what I was confused about in my question.

Comment: When you say the disposable won't have a reference to the `Where` observable, are you taking into account references held by closures?  I tend to be leery of closures because they can cause references to be kept around a lot longer than would otherwise be apparent.

Comment: @supercat Yes I was. See my edit. It is the *observer* that the dispose (created by the original source) will reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come to the conclusion with the help of Gideon's answer and breaking down a sample `Where` method:

I assumed incorrectly that each downstream `IObservable` was referenced by the upstream at all times (in order to push events down when needed). But this would root downstreams in memory for the lifetime of the upstream.

In fact, each upstream `IObservable` is referenced by the downstream `IObservable` (waiting, ready to hook an `IObserver` when required). This roots upstreams in memory as long as the downstream is referenced (which makes sense, as while a downstream in still referenced somewhere, a subscription may occur at any time).

However when a subscription does occur, this upstream to downstream reference chain does get formed, but only on the `IDisposable` implementation objects that manage the subscriptions at each observable stage, and only for the lifetime of that subscription. (which also makes sense - while a subscription exists, each upstream 'processing logic' must still be held in memory to handle the events being passed through to reach the final subscriber `IObserver`).

This gives a solution to both problems - while an `IObservable` is referenced, it will hold all source (upstream) `IObservables` in memory, ready for a subscription. And while a subscription exists, it will hold all downstream subscriptions in memory, allowing the final subscription to still receive events even though it's source `IObservable` may no longer be referenced.

Applying this to my example in my question, the `Where` and `Cast` downstream observables are very short lived - referenced up until the `Subscribe(observer)` call completes. They are then free to be collected. The fact that the intermediate observables may now be collected does not cause a problem for the subscription just created, as it has formed it's own subscription object chain (upstream -> downstream) that is rooted by the source `eventStream` observable. This chain will be released as soon as each downstream stage disposes its `IDisposable` subscription tracker.

Comment: This looks correct. One minor detail worth pointing out is that neither `Where` nor `Cast` make an `IDisposable` object, they make IObservable\IObserver objects (via something like Observable.Create).  Only one subscription is actually made (to eventStream in your case), otherwise all the observables would have to stay around.

Comment: Yes, but as a side effect of the Subscribe call on the observable returned by Cast, it subscribes up the chain to it's parent Where observable. Yes, the user-code only 'sees' one Subscribe call and one IDisposable, but inside that is another subscription to the parent, and inside that another, and so forth up the chain to the root. Correct?

Comment: I would not term them subscriptions. Instead, I would say that the operators wrap the observer such that a "WhereObserver" (or more precisely the anonymous observer created by the Where observable) is what is subscribed and does some processing before maybe calling the original observer.  It does not make its own IDisposable (which I took your 4th paragraph to imply) that wraps the IDisposable from eventStream. Mostly it's a terminology issue; you have the important ideas right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that `IObserable<T>` (like `IEnumerable<T>`) are lazy lists. They don't exist until someone tries to access the elements by subscribing or iterating.

When you write `list.Where(x => x > 0)` you are not creating a new list, you are merely defining what the new list will look like if someone tries to access the elements.

This is a very important distinction.

You can consider that there are two different IObservables. One is the definition and the subscribed instances.

The IObservable definitions use next to no memory. References can be freely shared. They will be cleanly garbage collected.

The subscribed instances only exist if someone is subscribed. They may use considerable memory. Unless you use the `.Publish` extensions you can't share references. When the subscription ends or is terminated by calling `.Dispose()` the memory is cleaned up.

A new set of subscribed instances are created for every new subscription. When the final child subscription is disposed the whole chain is disposed. They can't be shared. If there is a second subscription a complete chain of subscribed instances are created, independent of the first.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A class implementing `IObservable` is just a regular object. It will get cleaned up when the GC runs and does not see any references to it. It isn't anything other than "when does `new object()` get cleaned up". Except for memory use, whether they get cleaned up should not be visible to your program.

Comment: Yes, and not exactly, no. In Rx queries like these, each 'upstream' observable holds a reference to each 'downstream' observable (via a passed in IObserver I'm assuming). This roots the whole chain of observables in memory for the lifetime of the root observable. This causes issues if large numbers of these intermediate observables are created and hanging around processing events even though their final 'end-point' observers (the observers running your actual app logic) have long ago unsubscribed.

Comment: @Tyson That seems specific to the class implementing `IObservable`. There's no reason why an observable should continue observing another object if it is itself unobserved, and if it simply stops observing that other object, it will become unreferenced and get cleaned up properly.

Comment: @hvd: The problem is that when X is said to "observe" Y, what that really means is that X has to accept notifications when Y changes.  Whether or not anybody who's still alive cares about anything X might do in response to such notifications, the fact that X accepts such notifications will generally result in its being kept alive as long as Y is.

Comment: @supercat I understand that, I'm saying X shouldn't generally be accepting such notifications unless anything is in turn observing X: it should subscribe to Y if anything subscribes to X, and unsubscribe from Y when there are no subscribers to X. And judging from the other answers, that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If an object subscribes to events, whether for its own use, or for the purpose of forwarding them to other objects, the publisher of those events will generally keep it alive even if nobody else will.  If I'm understanding your situation correctly, you have objects which subscribe to events for the purpose of forwarding them to zero or more other subscribers.  I would suggest that you should if possible design your intermediate IObservables so that they will not subscribe to an event from their parent until someone subscribes to an event from them, and they will unsubscribe from their parent's event any time their last subscriber unsubscribes.  Whether or not this is practical will depend upon the threading contexts of the parent and child IObservables.  Further note that (again depending upon threading context) locking may be required to deal with the case where a new subscriber joins at about the same time as (what would have been) the last subscriber quits.  Even though most objects' subscription and unsubscription scenarios could be handled using `CompareExchange` rather than locking, that is often unworkable in scenarios involving interconnected subscription lists.

If your object will receive subscriptions and unsubscriptions from its children in a threading context which is not compatible with the parent's subscription and unsubscription methods (IMHO, `IObservable` should have required that all legitimate implementations allow subscription and unsubscription from arbitrary threading context, but alas it does not) you may have no choice but to have the intermediate IObservable, immediately upon creation, create a proxy object to handle subscriptions on your behalf, and have that object subscribe to the parent's event.  Then have your own object (to which the proxy would have only a weak reference) include a finalizer which will notify the proxy that it will need to unsubscribe when its parent's threading context permits.  It would be nice to have your proxy object unsubscribe when its last subscriber quits, but if a new subscriber might join and expect its subscription to be valid immediately, one may have to keep the proxy subscribed as long as anyone holds a reference to the intermediate observer which could be used to request a new subscription.

Comment: Interesting read! However my apologies, my question may have been misleading, I wasn't asking about implementing my own IObservables, but simply using the ones provided by the System.Reactive.Linq extension methods and how they root upstream/downstream observables in memory.